# process apparently never started in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo_cd@tmp/durable-9y3093

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline where I have declared dockerfile agent at the top level and the container is going to run on a slave node (not Jenkins master).

And in the post section, I am cloning some automation on the master node and trying to run those as the script.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            label 'demo'
            dir '.jenkins'
            args '--privileged --group-add docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
            additionalBuildArgs '--build-arg uid="$(id -u)" --build-arg gid="$(id -g)" --build-arg user_name="$(id -un)" --build-arg user_home="/home/jenkins" --build-arg docker_gid="$(getent group docker | cut -d: -f3)"'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Setup') {
            steps {
                sh "devcontainer up --workspace-folder ${env.WORKSPACE}  --remove-existing-container"
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh "devcontainer exec --workspace-folder ${env.WORKSPACE} ./build.sh -c all"
            }
        }
        stage('Upload') {
            when {
                expression { env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' }
            }
            steps {
                sh "devcontainer exec --workspace-folder ${env.WORKSPACE} ./build.sh -u"
            }
        }
    post {
        success {
            node ('master'){
            echo 'Build is Successful'
            script {
                   try{
                        //Clone automation in path /opt/demo/
                        obj.cloneAutomation()
                        def versioninfo = sh (script: cat /opt/demo/app1/version", returnStdout: true).trim()
                        echo "versioninfo : ${versioninfo}"
                   }catch(err) {
                       echo "${err.printStackTrace()}"
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here in the post section script fails to access the file I believe.

The error I am getting is :

20:05:51  process apparently never started in var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo_cd@tmp/durable-9y3093
20:05:51  (running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
20:05:51  Cannot contact : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo_cd@tmp/durable-9y3093/output.txt (No such file or directory)

Can someone please help me out here?

I tried creating a docker agent per stage but that did not help as here I am creating devcontainer in the setup stage and reusing the same in the build and upload stages.